# .NET SocketException - The requested name is valid, but no data of the requested type was found

Tags: iis, asp.net-mvc, .net-4.0

I've been scouring the web looking for someone who has had the same kind of error that I am experiencing but have come up dry.

I deployed a new ASP.NET web application to IIS and when I try to access the site I get the following Server error. It appears to be possibly network related but I really don't know for sure.

Thanks in advance!

```
[SocketException (0x2afc): The requested name is valid, but no data of the requested type was found]
System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg) +4729427
System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type) +1725
TIMSS.Messaging.ISynchronousMessageProcessor.ProcessSync(IMessage message) +0
TIMSS.Messaging.ClientSideImplementation.SimpleMessageDeliveryStrategy.ProcessSync(IMessage message) +159
TIMSS.PersonifyInitializer.CreateBaseRemotingContext(ISeatInformationProvider seatInformationProvider) +703
TIMSS.PersonifyInitializer.Authenticate(ISeatInformationProvider seatInformationProvider) +65
TIMSS.PersonifyInitializer.InitializeEnvironment(ISeatInformationProvider seatInformationProvider, String configDir) +57
TIMSS.PersonifyInitializer.Initialize(String configPath, ISeatInformationProvider seatInformationProvider) +142
ClubLocator.MvcApplication.Application_Start() +362

[HttpException (0x80004005): The requested name is valid, but no data of the requested type was found]
System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.EnsureAppStartCalledForIntegratedMode(HttpContext context, HttpApplication app) +4057733
System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +191
System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +352
System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +407
System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext) +375

[HttpException (0x80004005): The requested name is valid, but no data of the requested type was found]
System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +11702064
System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +141
System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr,  HttpContext context) +4870277
```

Comment: Did you [Google](https://www.google.co.uk/search?source=ig&rlz=&q=The+requested+name+is+valid%2C+but+no+data+of+the+requested+type+was+found) for the error? Some of the results suggest that it's a DNS issue - is the app trying to do a lookup, and if so does it have a valid DNS entry?

Comment: Chris, I did Google this and found the same types of answers, many related to network/dns issues. The app is not doing any lookups at startup or any other place for that matter

Comment: For me it turned out to be a DNS request time-out giving this exception